# Chaning the background color around a PDF in a UIWebView on Device

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, uiwebview, background

I'm using a webview to display a PDF.

The webview displays the PDF at it's actual size which is a little smaller than the size of the webvieww itself, revealing the scroll view underneath it.

I've tried setting the Webview to opaque and setting it's background color to another color, which works fine and dandy in the simulator, but fails to change the color on the device. On the device it changes the color of the background of the view behind the scroll view, this can be seen when the PDF is pulled all the way down.

I've also tried setting all the UIView's backgrounds, by iterating through the subviews but to no avail.

I've updated a diagram to help illustrate which area I'd like to color.

[Uploaded Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tolkT.jpg)

Comment: Hi, did you achieve what you wanted to ? I too want to change PDF page color to white. Can you help me ?

Comment: I ended up telling my employer it'd take more time than it was worth. And left it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't mess around with UIWebView's internals.

They can change anytime and your code might just crash on the next version of iOS.
If you need more control about pdf display, you might wanna take a look at other possibilities to show pdf, like using the CGPDFDrawPage* functions. Of course they are pretty low-level and it's a lot of work required until you can get fast page display, zooming, etc all right.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I only messed around with the internals as a test to see if it would do anything at all. And you're right using CGPDFDrawPage is a viable solution. It's just a lot of work to just change the background color. Your PDF library looks very nice by the way.